# Meta is an empty and soulless place (according to the Android app)

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I appear to have found a very strange bug.

When I click on a meta tag in a post, like [support](/questions/tagged/support), it leads to a borken URL, `empty/questions/tagged/foo`:

[image: soulless!]

This bug can be reproduced on [this post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1280/3808).

Comment: Borken URLs are like that!

Comment: `foo`? Why wasn't it `waffles` or `bacon` or something? This is blasphemous!

Comment: The style is also borken, only rendered as normal hyperlink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure enough - tagged question lists rendered in our webview had not been supported.  They will in the next release:  v1.0.25

As far as meta being an empty and soulless place, you said it - not me.  I find the emptiness comforting.